# Howto pass the parameter of next column in Link Template in spotfire

Tags: report, spotfire

[image]

As shown in the image if i mention {$}, it will take the current columns value and pass as a parameter to the queryString(URL). I am not able to figure out how to pass the first column (TM_TRANSMISSON_ID) value here, I tried the following and failed:
1.{$0}
2.{$TM_TRANSMISSION_ID}
3.[TM_TRANSMISSION_ID].

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a calculated column so that both values are in the same column? Since that is a column property I believe you can only access the specific column.

Comment: Actually  want to download an excel sheet as soon i click on the link count. 
I can t add new columns , i have to do on the current column itself

Comment: You have to concatenate there is no way to have {$} return anything but the whats in the column.